# Orable DB e MVC 4 - Erro de conexão (ORA-06413)

Tags: c#, oracle, asp.net-mvc-4

Tenho uma `dll` que é responsável por realizar as consultas no banco. Nessa `dll`, na classe de conexão, possuo um método que abre a conexão com o banco e me retorna a conexão, conforme por der visto abaixo:

```
private OracleConnection _IniciarConexao()
{
    ///Limpa as variáveis de erro
    this.UltimaExcecao = null;
    this.Erros         = new List<Exception>();

    OracleConnection conexao = null;

    try
    {
        conexao = new OracleConnection("Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=***)(PORT=***)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=****)(SERVER = DEDICATED))); User Id=***; Password=***;");

        conexao.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.UltimaExcecao = ex;
        this.Erros.Add(ex);
    }

    return conexao;
}
```

A `dll` utilizada para as referências do Oracle é a `System.Data.OracleClient.dll Versão 2.0.50727`.

Essa `dll` é consumida por uma aplicativo Web utilizando `MVC 4` com `C#` e o `.Net Framework 4.0`.

Quando utilizo essa `dll` em um projeto `Windows Forms` consigo conexão com o banco de dados sem problemas, porém quando utilizo em um sistema `MVC` ou `WebForms` ocorre um erro de conexão com o banco de dados.

O erro que ocorre é o `ORA-06413`. A imagem abaixo pode ilustrar o ocorrido:

[image: Erro de conexão]

Já estou no segundo dia de pesquisa sem sucesso sobre como resolver este problema.

Ao publicar o sistema no servidor de produção ele consegue conexão normalmente, porém no local, para utilizar o modo debug, não consigo conexão com o banco.

Alguém sabe como corrigir este erro, ou alguma fonte que possa me indicar para resolver este problema?

Comment: No servidor de banco Oracle tem os logs, verifique se essa conexão está chegando, ou verifique se está passando pelo firewall !!! Também tem o View Details na Exception verifique o dados mais detalhado do erro !!!

Comment: [Você está usando este pacote](https://www.nuget.org/packages/odp.net.x64/)? Ou ainda, [este outro](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/)?

Comment: Está usando o IIS completo ou o Express? O seu erro pode estar sendo causado por ter um client 32bit do Oracle e estar rodando uma aplicação 64bit, ou vice-versa. Tente alternar entre 32 e 64bit na sua aplicação (direto no pool se for IIS ou no Visual Studio se for o Express).

Comment: @Cezar vou verificar os logos do banco e a questão do firewall. Os detalhes da exceção não tem nada, já olhei diversas vezes.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez não estou usando nenhum pacote Nuget, apenas a própria dll que é utilizada nos projetos da empresa.

Comment: Então é isto. Vou responder.

Comment: @MarcusVinicius Estou usando o IIS Express, que vem com o VS 2013 Express For Web. Vou verificar essa questão que você falou

Comment: A opção para usar a versão 64bit do IIS Express fica em `TOOLS > Options > Projects And Solutions > Web Projects > [x] Use the 64 bit version of IIS Express for web sites and projects`

Comment: @MarcusVinicius a sua solução funcionou. Se quiser postar uma resposta eu aceito ela.

Comment: @RichardDias publiquei a resposta com uma explicação de como configurar 32/64bit em apps Web .Net (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/92072/23593)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esse erro é comumente causado por incompatibilidade de arquiteturas entre a DLL do Oracle e a aplicação que está rodando. Se estiver usando a versão 64bit da DLL por exemplo, em projetos Web, deve-se configurar o Pool de aplicativos do IIS para usar 64bit ou ativar a configuração do IIS Express no Visual Studio, se for o caso:

- **Se estiver usando o IIS**, por padrão ele roda como 64bit. Se precisar forçar 32bit, Dentro do Gerenciado do IIS, expanda "Application Pools", localize o Pool que sua aplicação está usando, clique direito > Advanced Settings:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sup>Se a configuração "Enable 32-Bit Applications" estiver como `True`, o pool rodará como 32bit, caso contrário, como 64bit.</sup>

- **Se estiver usando o IIS Express**, dentro do Visual Studio, Vá em `TOOLS > Options > Projects And Solutions > Web Projects >` e marque o checkbox "Use the 64 bit version of IIS Express for web sites and projects":

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Adicionar a DLL diretamente pode ser um problema, sobretudo considerando que pode haver uma mudança de ambientes na hora de publicar sua aplicação.

Ao invés de adicionar a DLL diretamente, utilize [o pacote NuGet oficial dos drivers da Oracle](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/):

```
PM> Install-Package Oracle.ManagedDataAccess
```

Comment: Na dll que faz o acesso ao Banco a versão do .Net é a 3.5. Esse pacote não dá para essa versão. Sei que referenciar a DLL diretamente não é a melhor opção, mas é o costume utilizado até o momento na empresa. Em breve iremos mudar isso, mas até lá temos que usar assim.

Comment: Aí complica. O jeito é forçar 64 bits, conforme o @MarcusVinicius colocou. Não tem como usar um *framework* mais recente?

Comment: Por enquanto não, pois existem vários sistemas que são antigos e rodam sobre o 3.5. Consegui criar um novo utilizando o 4.0 para mostrar algumas vantagens, mas ainda assim não é possível mudar todos os aplicativos. Por isso a dll que é compartilhada deve manter essa versão.

Answer (score 1):

Creio que achei o problema.

Eu estava testando um projeto que era uma aplicação de console, utilizando uma dll de acesso à banco de dados Oracle idêntica à do problema.
O arquivo .csproj estava configurado como abaixo:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
 <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
 <DebugType>full</DebugType>
 <Optimize>false</Optimize>
 <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
 <DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG</DefineConstants>
 <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
 <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
 <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Entretanto, quando fui pesquisar como estava o arquivo .csproj da minha aplicação console, ela estava da forma abaixo:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
 <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
 <Optimize>true</Optimize>
 <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
 <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
 <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
 <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
 <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
</PropertyGroup>
```

A solução foi copiar essa seção do .csproj da dll, substituindo o trecho do .csproj da minha aplicação console pelo trecho da dll. 
Após a substituição o problema estava resolvido. Creio que o VS2015 estava se perdendo quando salvava as dlls a serem utilizadas, salvando uma parte na pasta bin/Release e outra na pasta bin/Debug.

Answer (score 1):

A resposta do @MarcusVinicius resolveu o meu problema para projetos web, porém continuei com um problema para aplicativos desktop, como `windows forms` e `console aplication`.

Observando a resposta do @HendrigWernner percebi a tag `<Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>`. Olhei as propriedades do projeto e desmarquei esta opção nas propriedades do projeto, na aba `build`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fazendo esta modificação o projeto funcionou corretamente e o erro de conexão não apareceu mais.