# Oracle DB e MVC 4 apresentando erro ORA-06413

Tags: c#, oracle, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

Estou tendo um problema [muito semelhante à esse aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92050/orable-db-e-mvc-4-erro-de-conex%c3%a3o-ora-06413). Resumindo, tenho uma aplicação que roda com o ASP.NET MVC 4, utilizando .NET Framework 4.0, utilizando a mesma DLL de acesso ao Oracle, a `System.Data.OracleClient.dll` Versão 2.0.50727.

Realizei o que foi sugerido nas respostas e o problema persiste.

Testei dois cenários:

1. Ao utilizar o servidor IIS Express configurado para 64 bits, o sistema apresenta o erro

   > OCIEnvCreate falhou com código de retorno -1, mas o texto da mensagem de erro não estava disponível
2. Ao rodar a aplicação utilizando o IIS Express configurado para rodar em 32 bits o mesmo apresenta o erro

   > ORA-06413

Alguém já teve o erro semelhante? Ao usar a mesma DLL em uma aplicação WinForms o erro não ocorre e o sistema conecta no Oracle sem maiores problemas.

Comment: Por "forms" você se refere ao Windows Forms?

Comment: Sim. Essa outra aplicação utiliza Windows Forms e tenho uma outra aplicação em console que também funciona com a mesma DLL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Possíveis causas:**

- Usar uma versão não suportada do Oracle Client (mais antigo que 11.2)
  no Windows 7 ou superior a essa versão.
- As `DLLs` de uma instalação anterior do Oracle Client foram deixadas
  no sistema, causando um conflito.

**Soluções:**

- Instale uma versão suportada do Oracle Client.
- DLLs conflitantes, resultante de instalação anterior do Oracle.

Para o segundo item das soluções faça uma pesquisa de "OCI.DLL" na máquina local. Se você encontra-la em qualquer local diferente do seu `ORACLE_HOME` exclua-o. Exemplo de "oci.dll" fora do diretório `ORACLE_HOME`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se for necessário, tente desinstalar o Oracle Client e execute a pesquisa novamente. Se encontrar alguma coisa, isso que pode estar causando o erro.

Se o sistema estiver publicado no ISS, após remover as DLLs, faça o recycle pool da sua aplicação.

Comment: De fato. Resolvi desinstalando o Oracle completamente na minha máquina (excluindo, inclusive, qualquer registro dele no sistema) e instalando o Client 11.2. Após isso, funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

Creio que achei o problema.

Eu estava testando um projeto que era uma aplicação de console, utilizando a mesma dll de acesso à banco de dados Oracle do problema deste tópico.
O arquivo .csproj estava configurado como abaixo:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
 <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
 <DebugType>full</DebugType>
 <Optimize>false</Optimize>
 <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
 <DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG</DefineConstants>
 <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
 <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
 <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Entretanto, quando fui pesquisar como estava o arquivo .csproj da minha aplicação console, ela estava da forma abaixo:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
 <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
 <Optimize>true</Optimize>
 <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
 <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
 <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
 <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
 <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
</PropertyGroup>
```

A solução foi copiar essa seção do .csproj da dll, substituindo o trecho do .csproj da minha aplicação console pelo trecho da dll. 
Após a substituição o problema estava resolvido. Creio que o VS2015 estava se perdendo quando salvava as dlls a serem utilizadas, salvando uma parte na pasta bin/Release e outra na pasta bin/Debug.